# Does Pre-boot encryption works on all drives or just the C drive

Tags: windows, disk-encryption

Does Pre-boot encryption works on all drives or just the C drive?

where does the recoverykey store

Comment: What encryption are you talking about? Bitlocker? You tagged this with `windows`, but what specifically are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean BitLocker, by default it only encrypts the C drive. You can, however, encrypt additional data drives on the system, and you do not even need boot drive encryption enabled in order to use BitLocker on a data drive.

Encrypting a data drive on Windows 10 Pro is fairly trivial - you right click the drive in Explorer, then click Turn on BitLocker. You then enter a password to encrypt the drive. You then save your recovery key somewhere safe - not on the encrypted machine!

If you have boot drive encryption enabled, you may choose to enable the "Automatically unlock this drive on my computer" option. This causes the drive to be automatically unlocked when you boot Windows, without needing to manually unlock the drive with a password once the system boots.

You can even turn the "Use a password to unlock the drive" option off, meaning that the only way to decrypt the drive is by unlocking the encrypted boot drive, but I strongly recommend against this for safety purposes. People lose their BitLocker recovery keys all the time. If you suffer a boot disk failure and do not have the recovery key for the data disk, you will lose all the files on the boot disk **and** all the files on the data disk. By setting a password, you can recover the files from the data disk on another computer even if you lose the recovery key.